# Maven Invoker: IllegalStateException

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module Maven project (https://github.com/veniltonjr/msplearning)

One of my modules ***I need run programmatically the command from Maven build "clean install*"**, but when I invoke the execution of these goals the following error occurs:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` **Maven application directory was not specified, and ${maven.home} is not provided in the system properties. Please specify at least on of these.**

In the [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html) documentation is said that M2_HOME environment variable must exist.

Already have this variable set in my SO. This should not be enough to make the method `invoke` work? Follows the code snippet where I run the method in question:

```
Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.setLocalRepositoryDirectory(new File("C:\\git\\msplearning"));

InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("clean", "install"));
InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request); // Exception occours here...
```

Already, thanks!

**EDITED (The Solution)**

I had to set the POM and also set the Maven Home, which in my case is in the M3_HOME environment variable:

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile(new File("C:\\git\\msplearning\\pom.xml"));
request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("verify"));

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("M3_HOME")));
InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
```

Thanks @RobertScholte and @khmarbaise!

Comment: Why do you need to run such a command? Doesn't a `mvn install` on the root level work?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @khmarbaise. When I run mvn install on the root level the build is completed successfully. But I need to run this programmatically command because I need to provide the output artifact in a RESTful service.

Comment: @veniltonjr To execute the above code do you need Maven installed on your machine or just a few jar files are enough??

Comment: Hi @Lucy! This solution, specifically, uses the environment variable of MV3_HOME configured on the server. Therefore the Maven installation is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either set the `request.pomFile` or `request.baseDirectory` so the Invoker knows from which directory or file Apache Maven should be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RobertScholte! But none of the options worked. Do you have any more suggestions for this problem? Perform the method `invoke` on the service [ProductRESTfulServer](https://github.com/veniltonjr/msplearning/blob/master/restful-app/src/main/java/com/msplearning/restful/app/ProductRESTfulServer.java), which is in one of the modules of my parent project ([msplearning](https://github.com/veniltonjr/msplearning)).

Comment: I think Karl-Heinz asked the correct question. *What* are you trying to build? Which pom.xml?

Comment: I really want to build the pom of parent project: `msplearning/pom.xml`

Comment: Aren't you confusing buildtime with runtime? I don't the any reason why you need to rebuild the project during runtime. I tried to build your project but I'm missing the ANDROID_HOME. A few remarks: your project can only be built with M3.0.x, not with M3.1.x+ (doesn't have to be a problem, though). And during development the version must always and with -SNAPSHOT.

Comment: My context will be the following: I have a RESTful service that receives an Id that will be set in a .properties file of my project android-app.
The aim of this service is to run a build for the modified .properties to be encapsulated in the resulting APK. Again thanks for the help!

Comment: That means that you need the sources of that project. Either checkout to the sources in TMP_android-app directory (for instance) or include http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#project and unpack it in TMP_android-app. Now set request.baseDir to TMP_android-app and run `verify` (not 'clean install', too much overhead)

Comment: Thanks @Robert!!! To solve the problem with the ${maven.home} had to set the MavenHome in Involer object. Tried running the `clean install`, but the maven-clean-plugin could not delete the file androidannotations.log on target folder. Thus the `verify` or `install` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running from a Maven-Surefire unit test then it's best to request that Surefire passes the `maven.home` system property on to its child processes. Per https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html you can do this by adding the following config stanza:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version> <!-- see surefire-page for available versions -->
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```