# Location of Maven Home on Cloud Foundry

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry, maven-invoker-plugin

I have an application that programmatically runs Maven command "clean package" at runtime, using plugin maven-invoker.
To be able to run this application on Cloud Foundry, we need to set Maven Home on the invoker.

This question is similar to [Maven Invoker: IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200189/maven-invoker-illegalstateexception), except that we are deploying on Cloud Foundry but don't know how to get the value for Maven Home.

Is it possible to get it from CF environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java build pack does not install Maven or set any Maven related environment variables.  You can however set whatever environment variables that you like via `cf set-env` or in the `env` block of your manifest.yml file.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block

Your app when running on CF will run as the `vcap` user and it runs out of `/home/vcap/app` (or reference $HOME env variable).  If you need to pick a location to use for Maven home, I would suggest putting it under that directory.