# Run Maven Invoker from Java fails

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-invoker-plugin

I'm using Maven Invoker to run some maven command in Java code. Here are the references I read before doing my own code:

[maven-invoker-illegal-state-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200189/maven-invoker-illegalstateexception), [how-to-run-maven-from-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java), [Maven Invoker Usage](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html)

And my code is like:

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile(new File("absolute/path/of/pom.xml"));
request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("clean", "install"));

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.setMavenHome(new File("absolute/path/of/maven/"));
invoker.setWorkingDirectory(new File("./")); //will fail with or without this line

InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
System.out.println(result.getExitCode());
```

The `ExitCode` I get is always 1, which means there is a build fail. However, I can correctly execute all Maven command from the command line.

Also I'd like to download the dependencies declared in `pom.xml` by using `request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("dependency:copy-dependencies", "-DoutputDirectory=OUTPUT_DIR"));` by referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742252/how-to-use-maven-pom-to-download-jar-files-only-to-a-specific-directory). The `maven-dependency_plugin` is correctly included in the `pom.xml`.

Is it because I'm writing a multi-module project and all this is under one module not from the root? If so what is the right way to do this? Thanks a lot.

---

**Update**:

Finally I referred to [this page](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-run-external-programs-by-using-java-processbuilder-class/189) and changed to use `ProcessBuilder` instead and that works.

But still I don't unserstand why the `Invoker` fails for me. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have multi module project which is not in root... you should refactor your multi module project...What is the problem here? Furthermore what about using `request.setDebug( true );` to see what's the problem? And furthermore you can set on the `invoker.setErrorHandler( InvocationOutputHandler errorHandler )` ...Apart from that where is the pom.xml you would to run located which is the important part for the workingDirectory?

Comment: I always have `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Java\jdk1.8_77\\bin"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation` but this path is the installation path. The pom is under `module/pom.xml` and the java file is under `module/src/main/java/RunPom.java`.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your reply. The objectif is to make sure each module can be compiled and packaged seperately.