# Maven Invoker cannot find MAVEN_HOME environment variable on Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, maven-invoker-plugin

I have built a Java web application that receives a url from a form and performs TestNG tests against those URLs using a local Maven installation from the command line. My test classes are in src/main/java which is not conventional, but since my tests are run after my build, I moved them there.

When I use the Maven invoker from my servlet in Eclipse's Tomcat, my tests run without issue and provide an outputted result in my web application. The problem that I am having is that when I export my application as a .war file and put it in the webapps folder of my local Tomcat server on my Windows machine, my local Maven installation cannot  be found.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Maven application directory was not specified, and ${maven.home} is not provided in the system properties. Please specify at least on of these.
```

...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Maven application directory was not specified, and ${maven.home} is not provided in the system properties. Please specify at least on of these.
    org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenCommandLineBuilder.checkRequiredState(MavenCommandLineBuilder.java:127)
    org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenCommandLineBuilder.build(MavenCommandLineBuilder.java:62)
    org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.execute(DefaultInvoker.java:100)
    com.xxxxx.qa.servlets.RunTestServlet.doPost(RunTestServlet.java:104)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is the Maven Invoker code that I am using:

```
InvocationRequest invocationRequest = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
invocationRequest.setPomFile( new File( "pom.xml" ) );
invocationRequest.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "test surefire-report:report " + formatTest));
Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker(); 
invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")));                        
InvocationResult result = invoker.execute( invocationRequest);
```

I have no issues running Maven commands from the command line and have correctly added my Maven directory to my MAVEN_HOME environment variable.

I tried some of the answers offered on this page but did not have any success - [Maven Invoker: IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200189/maven-invoker-illegalstateexception)

I also tried running a Tomcat setevn.bat batch file in Tomcat-Home/bin:

```
set "maven.home=C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0"
```

...

```
set "MAVEN_HOME=C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a maven plugin ? Or are these test a kind of integration tests? And what is the role of Tomcat here?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on how to set [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation) (or anything else).

You don't need Maven to run TestNG, see [run TestNg programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically).

Comment: Running TestNG programmatically is a great work-around solution and actually works better than invoking Maven from what I can see. I still find it strange that I cannot access the MAVEN_HOME environment variable. As I already noted, I already set up the environment variable for this and have no issues running Maven from the command-line.

Comment: It seems after some testings, running TestNg programmatically is working for me in Eclipse's Tomcat but does not work on my local Tomcat, so this is not solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")))
```

with

```
invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv().get("MAVEN_HOME")))
```